# Best way to check when app goes offline in ionic 2 app

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, ionic2

I've got an app that has the ability to perform certain functionalities via an offline mode. A couple of examples of this are:

1. When the app is offline, the green light next to a user profile turns yellow.
2. Certain list item documents grey out if the items weren't downloaded for offline view, thus only documents that were downloaded for offline view are not greyed out and can be viewed.

The easiest and most straight-forward seems to just have some sort of a function that checks `navigator.onLine` like

```
export class OfflineService {
  public isOffline : boolean = false;

  constructor() {}

  checkOffline() {
    if (!navigator.onLine) {
      this.isOffline = true;
    } else {
      thus.isOffline = false;
    }
  }

}
```

And check it when certain actions are performed, such as a download of a document, maybe as often as a state change from page to page, or before every time a normal HTTP request would be made through a service to hit an API.

What would be the best way to check and maintain this state across an app so that if the device does happen to go offline, my pages change to reflect that (like the two points above with a status light, or greying certain line items out that cannot be accessed while offline)

Comment: Have you looked into this : http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install Network plugin and subscribe to disconnect and connect events, like this:

```
import { Network } from 'ionic-native';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

export class SomeClass {
  constructor(public platform: Platform){
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // IN CASE THE USER DISCONNECT
      Network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
        //DO YOUR CODE, SAVE SOMETHING ON LOCALDATABASE, CALL FUNCTION, ETC.
      }

      // IN CASE USER RECONECCT BACK
      Network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
       // DO CODE
      });
    }
  }
}
```

When i want to check everytime or in every page if the user ir connected or not, instead of repeating this code on every page i simply use it on `app.components` and, on connect or disconnect i save a `conn` variable in the localStorage that's a `boolean`, so when i'm doing connection sensitive work i check in the `localStorage` if the `conn` is `true` or `false`.

That way works fine and fast for me and probably will work fine for you too.

Hope that helps